# could anyone explain the meaning of lomb_scargle in scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signals

I am trying to find period in my unevenly spaced timing points.
Fortunately the *lomb-scargle* method is very appropriate to do this.
However the output confuses me much. Suppose a `sin(2*pi*t)` curve as below, we should expect a sharp peak at *frequency = 1 Hz*, BUT the output deviates much.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import spectral
import pylab as pl

time = np.linspace(1, 1000, 100)
intensity = np.sin(2*np.pi*time)
freqs1 = np.linspace(0.01, 10, 1000)
freqs2 = np.linspace(0.01, 10, 100)
pm1 = spectral.lombscargle(time, intensity, freqs1)
pm2 = spectral.lombscargle(time, intensity, freqs2)

pl.subplot(211)
pl.plot(freqs1, pm1)
pl.subplot(212)
pl.plot(freqs2, pm2)
pl.show()
```

[image: spectra]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sampling rate is way too low to distinguish the 2 pi component in range t=1...1000, so you end up with lots of [aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing). You need around 10000 points to sample sin(2 pi t) in range t=1...1000 to reasonable accuracy.

To understand, do `plot(time, intensity)`. After that, do it again with `time = np.linspace(1, 1000, 10000)`.

Finally, keep in mind that Lomb-Scargle gives the result in terms of angular frequency.